# Is there a way to mimic photoshop's overlay filter with CSS?

Tags: css, photoshop

The overlay blend alters the color of the image on top, as opposed to just altering the transparency. Is there a way to mimic this with CSS? Just exporting a photoshop image with the layer set to overlay and placing it over a background on the web page doesn't work.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It can't be done with pure css, but it can be done with javascript. Check out [Pixastic's blend function](http://web.archive.org/web/20140830094242/https://www.pixastic.com/lib/docs/actions/blend/), it has ~20 blending methods that match those in photoshop.

*Note: this answer has become less accurate over the years. The `mix-blend-mode` attribute now works across most browsers, and pixastic seems to have disappeared.*

Comment: +1 wow, very nice.  FYI to the OP, it's theoretically possible to incorporate something like this into CSS, but you'd have to parse the stylesheets to pull out rules and then process them with JS.

Answer (score 1):

I'm late to the party, but there is now a `mix-blend-mode` css property that applies blend mode to an entire element which takes into account the elements below.

Answer (score 0):

now you can do it with CSS but only in modern browser, try `background-blend-mode: multiply;`
it blend the background-image of an element with its background-color.