# CSS - transparent pngs vs Photoshop layer types

Tags: css, photoshop

I've just created Photoshop mockup and all the shadow & highlight layers are set to "overlay" instead of "normal".

After I save them as .png and display on my site they look horrible, as Photoshop uses filters and png/css don't.

Is there any way of fixing it?

**I can't save the highlight as .jpg / .png file with background, it needs to be saved as semi-transparent .png and placed over background image using multiple backgrounds technique**.

Any hints / ideas? Tried playing with opacity / highlight color, but still far from perfection. Maybe there's some CSS way?

[image: PS Overlay vs .png]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a solution, but in javascript. No way how to do that in css.

http://web.archive.org/web/20140830094242/https://www.pixastic.com/lib/docs/actions/blend/

Answer (score 2):

Short answer: no.

Long answer: You have two options and neither of them involves doing it in CSS:

1. Use one of the JavaScript plugins out there that will replicate
   these functions with some complex calculations (an example of one
   can be found in the comment Vladimir Volek left on the original
   question:
   [Is there a way to mimic photoshop's overlay filter with CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6587272/is-there-a-way-to-mimic-photoshops-overlay-filter-with-css)).
2. It's generally possible to recreate these effects using different
   (and more time-consuming, case-by-case methods) in Photoshop. I'll usually ask the
   designer if he/she can go back and re-do them if they have time, and
   if not, I'll spend wayyy too much time doing it myself. I hate to
   use JS for a silly presentational thing like this.

Answer (score 1):

I have had the exact same problem... the way I have found to do this is to try to recreate the image using opacity instead of overlay. With the image you attached above... you can probably use the gradient tool with colors Black to transparent. Apply them to a new layer and then change the opacity down until you like it. Then you can remove the background and save it as a png.